# How can I populate a List from a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

As part of my assignment, we are given an interface which we can't change, and some pre-defined tests to use to develop our methods.

The interface is as follows:

```
public interface ContactTracer {
    public void addCourse(String courseID, String courseName);
    public void addStudent(String id, String name, String email);
    public void loadStudentCourseList(Map<String, String> enrolments);
    
    public String getStudentName(String studentID);
    public String getStudentEmail(String studentID);
    public String getCourseForStudent(String studentID);
    public String getCourseName(String courseID);
    public List<String> findStudentsForCourse(String courseID);
    public List<String> findContacts(String studentID);
}
```

The particular test I'm running:

```
@Test
void testLoadStudentCourseList()    {
    ContactTracer ct = new PartOneContactTracer();
    Map<String, String> enrolments = new HashMap<>();
    enrolments.put("S101", "SOFT01");
    enrolments.put("S102", "NET02");
    enrolments.put("S103", "SOFT01");
    ct.loadStudentCourseList(enrolments);
    List<String> students = ct.findStudentsForCourse("SOFT01");
    assertEquals(2, students.size());
    assertTrue(students.contains("S101"));
    assertTrue(students.contains("S103"));
}
```

And the method I need to create from the test:

```
@Override
public List<String> findStudentsForCourse(String courseID) {
    return null;
}
```

I can tell from the test that within the `findStudentsForCourse` method I need to create `List<String> students` and fill it with matching students from the enrolments Map, and then return the the List.

I have created the following fields:-

```
public class PartOneContactTracer implements ContactTracer {
    
    private Map<String, String> courseDetails = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> studentName = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> studentEmail = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> enrolments = new HashMap<>();

    ...
}
```

What I can't get my head around is how to pass the data in the enrolments Map into the students List in order to make the Assertion in the test true.

Comment: Did you implement `loadStudentCourseList` yet? You need to show us that. You won't be able to implement a method to search through some data until you've implemented the method which *populates the data*. Because how do you expect to be able to search through nothing? (well you can, but the answer will always be the same: nothing)

Comment: @Michael I think that he question is about how implement the method, but if he doesn't tried yet, yes,  he is expecting that someone do his work and not help with a problem.

Comment: @Michael You're of course right, it is the `loadStudentCourseList` I need help with, I don't know why I have included the `findStudentsForCourse` method. Obviously confusing myself. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Kaneda it was a genuine mistake on my part, I am not trying to get anyone to do my work for me, just after some guidance.

Comment: Think of every map as set of A-to-B relationships, because that's what a map is. I like to name them that way too. So all my maps are named something like `idToStudent`. The ID is the key, the student is the value. In your case you have a few maps which don't make sense to me. Take `studentName`. What does it represent? Is it name to something? Is it ID to name? Something else?

Comment: @RaoulDuke316 don't get me wrong I'm not judging you, just clarifying, I wanna discuss and help of course ^^.

Comment: @Michael the studentName had studentID as the key and name as the value, & studentEmail has the studentID as the key and email as the value. These maps were created to satisfy another test.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a list and fill it just search through the map all the keys (students) that has the value (course id):

```
public List<String> findStudentsForCourse(String courseId) {
    return enrolments.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(courseId))
        .map(e -> e.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @Michael I made a mistake, I want to show just how he can do this without filling the list. In my point of view doesn't make sense fill a list if you need search information using the key or value of the list (in this situation of course)